# How to implement a pagination feature with scan or any dynamodb method?

Tags: node.js, npm, amazon-dynamodb

I see this can be used to limit the display of results. Using [dynamodb](https://github.com/baseprime/dynamodb) npm library.

```
Account.scan().limit(10).exec(printResults);
```

But how do I tell the scan method to start from a particular record? Basically what I need is a `getAll` method for my custom Database access layer. I found the `getItems` method but it requires indexes to load models. So it loads specific models only. I need all records paginated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the dynamodb [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.Pagination)

> A single Scan only returns a result set that fits within the 1 MB size
>   limit. To determine whether there are more results and to retrieve
>   them one page at a time, applications should do the following:
>
> 1. Examine the low-level Scan result:
>      If the result contains a LastEvaluatedKey element, proceed to step 2.
>      If there is not a LastEvaluatedKey in the result, then there are no more items to be retrieved.
> 2. Construct a new Scan request, with the same parameters as the previous one. However, this time, take the LastEvaluatedKey value from
>      step 1 and use it as the ExclusiveStartKey parameter in the new Scan
>      request.
> 3. Run the new Scan request.
> 4. Go to step 1.

Looking at the dynamodb npm from your link...

> ```
>  // Load 20 accounts
> Account
>   .scan()
>   .limit(20)
>   .exec();
>
> // Load All accounts, 20 at a time per request
> Account
>   .scan()
>   .limit(20)
>   .loadAll()
>   .exec();
> ```

But it appears that `startKey` may directly corresponds to `ExclusiveStartKey`

```
// Start scan using start key
Account
  .scan()
  .where('age').notNull()
  .startKey('foo@example.com')
  .exec()
```

Comment: I found I can implement a next page feature with limit and startKey method of the package. But I don't see how to go back and forth and implement a use case where user requests a particular page! 

`var a = this.model.scan().limit(params.Limit);
  a = Object.keys(params.ExclusiveStartKey).length
    ? a.startKey(params.ExclusiveStartKey)
    : a;

  a.exec(function(error, data) {
    callback(null, returnArray);
  });`

`?page=4&lastKey=xxxxxx`

Comment: @SmokingSheriff dynamo doesn't really support that functionality.